# Hi My Django Forms.cleaned_data is not giving me any output. Can someone help me?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am trying to create a page to generate passwords and the user will select either level 0 or level 1 for varying strengths of the password. And I am not able to get the users selection of level 0 or level 1 using the radio button.

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import random
import string
from types import NoneType
from random_word import RandomWords
from .forms import CHOICES

def password(request):
    passw = passGenAdvanced()
    form = CHOICES(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        selected = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        print(selected)

    return render(request, 'generator/password.html', {"password":passw})
```

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
password = [('0','Level 0'), ('1', 'Level 1')]
class CHOICES(forms.Form):
    password = forms.ChoiceField(choices=password, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

My html file

```
{% extends 'generator/base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<style>
    .button {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="password" id="Level0">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="password">Level 0</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="password" id="Level1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="password">Level 1</label>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<h5 class="alert alert-success">Your Generated Password: <strong>{{password}}</strong></h5> 
{% endblock %}
```

Sorry if the problem may seem obvious, I am new to django.

After printing out the form.error it keeps saying this ["on"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w79xX.png) it isn't even one of my radio options. So how does it give me that?

Comment: Is the form valid?

Comment: yeah I just checked and the form is not valid, nothing is getting outputted in the if form.isvalid statement. So how do I make it valid?

Comment: I have modified my question to include the output from form.error hopefully that will help in diagnosing my problems. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radio inputs are missing the value so add value for each radio and try again.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! <3, I cant believe it was something that simple.